# Angular Nested Router Outlet Children Disappear Before Router Animation Completes

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

**THE SCENARIO**

I have an Angular app with nested routing. The parent router outlet has a sliding animation. One of the child components (essentially one of the root pages), has a router outlet of its own, the child router outlet does not animate though.

**THE ISSUE**

The sliding animation works fine among all root components. However, when I'm at the root component with a nested router outlet, a strange thing happens. If I navigate out of it to another root component, its contents (current child component) disappears before the route animation finishes.

**AN EXAMPLE**

I created the following stackblitz to illustrate the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9gbzax

In the example, if you navigate between pages 1 and 2, no issue would appear. If you try to navigate from page3.child1 to either page 1 or page 2, the contents (the child component) will disappear before the animation terminates. Is there any way I can make the contents persist until the animation ends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I was able to solve the issue, though in a hacky way. What I did is to animate the children of the leaving route. I added the following in the group animation:

```
query(':leave *', [
    style({}),
    animate(1, style({}))
], optional)
```

To see the solution in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7gskcz, the solution is the last couple of lines in the file animations.ts